# Deploying an app on previously created app name in heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i deploy an app on heroku  damp-woodland-6747 .and deployed a rail app . now i want to deploy a node app on this app name.how to do this  ??please guideline

in past i mainly run two commands

```
heroku create

git push heroku master
```

Comment: heroku git:remote -a damp-woodland-6747 .we have to run this command ??

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't allow two apps with the same name.

So, what you can do is delete the old app from heroku or change its name, log into Heroku's site, go to your new Node App, and set the name in the app's "Settings" to damp-woodland-6747.

Comment: i want to replace first rail app to this current node app and the domain should be same damp-woodland-6747.herokuapp.com .perhaps u didn't get my problem correctly

Comment: i mean on this domain i want to deploy my app  damp-woodland-6747.herokuapp.com

Comment: If you remove your original app and change the name of your new app in "Settings" to damp-woodland-6747, your new app will be available at the endpoint damp-woodland-6747.herokuapp.com.

Comment: i am not able to create a new app when i run command heroku create 
 !    You've reached the limit of 5 apps for unverified accounts.
 !    Add a credit card to verify your account.
and i dont have credit card now

Comment: Are you still planning on keeping the old Rails app on Heroku for anything? If not, delete it from Heroku, push your new Node app, and then change the name in "Settings" to damp-woodland-6747.