# Can I reuse an old (deleted) heroku app name?

Tags: heroku

I know heroku doesn't allow two apps with the same name. However, will it allow an app name to be reused if the app has been deleted? Or is the name of a deleted app reserved forever?

I have a heroku app I want to replace, and the old setup is not useful. This includes some config and db settings - it's not just a matter of redeploying. My simplest approach is to delete the app completely and start over. But I don't want to delete it without first checking whether I will be able to recreate it with the same name.

Comment: If you delete your own app, than yes that should work because u make that name available again

Comment: It is possible, according to this:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279168/deploying-an-app-on-previously-created-app-name-in-heroku